# Windows 7 , CPU usage hikes up to 100%

Tags: windows-7, performance, cpu-usage, lag

I am having this issue of lag in Windows 7 Professional, the CPU usage is 100%, even if I am only watching video on GOM player, nothing else is open, but the usage is 100%, or if I open Firefox/Chrome the usage becomes 100%, I need to restart the system to get rid of this. It occurs many times a day.I thought that windows might have the issues, I installed it twice but the same issue occurs.
My friend told me that it might be low voltage issue, but even on battery power, I am having the 100% usage issue.

(System Specs : core i5, 4GB ram, 500GB HDD, intel HD card)

I am uploading image of my task manager:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Add your system specifications to your question.  How did you reinstall Windows?  (using the actual Microsoft disk or your laptop's recovery tools)

Comment: @kaibuki: Which process is hogging the CPU, exactly?

Comment: @breahthrough : Yes using the CD, I formatted the C partition, and installed the windows , fresh copy on the partition

Comment: @Mehrdad : that is the the issues, system Idle Process it is taking the max CPU usage...all other apps which I run the hardly take more than 20% of usage.

Comment: @kaibuki: from you comment it seems you have AVG **and** Avast installed at the same time? If that's the case it is no wonder your computer is slow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

System *Idle* Process doesn't take up CPU. It's a dummy process telling you how much of the CPU is ***idle***, hence the name.

There's no problem with your computer.

Comment: I know its a dummy process, but again why my system getting slow and lag  more than usual , I have traced one process avgchsva.exe, I found it taking 40+% of CPU usage, but now its calm.

Comment: @kaibuki: Surprise! Notice that `avgchsva` starts with **AVG**. i.e. your antivirus is functioning normally. :)